# Inserting datetime with stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

My DAL is throwing this error saying that it can't convert `datetime` to `int` but I can't see where it founds an int. The error reads:

> Implicit conversion from data type datetime to int is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query

My code is:

```
   public static void  CreateExemplaire( DateTime date_achat , DateTime date_emprunt)
    {
        SqlCommand oUpd = new SqlCommand();

    try
    {
        clsDatabase.oDataBase.Open();

        oUpd.Connection = clsDatabase.oDataBase;

        oUpd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        oUpd.CommandText = "examplaire_Create";


        SqlParameter oParamAchat = new SqlParameter("@date_achat", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        oParamAchat.Value = date_achat;

        SqlParameter oParamEmprunt = new SqlParameter("@date_emprunt",SqlDbType.DateTime);
        oParamEmprunt.Value = date_emprunt;
        oUpd.Parameters.Add(oParamAchat);
        oUpd.Parameters.Add(oParamEmprunt);

        int RowsInserted = oUpd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (RowsInserted == 0)
            throw new BusinessError.CustomError(6);

    }
    catch (SqlException exSQL)
    {
        int IdError = 999;
        switch (exSQL.Number)
        {
            case 18456:
                IdError = 1;
                break;
            case 8152:
                IdError = 5;
                break;
        }

        throw new BusinessError.CustomError(IdError);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        int IdError = 999;

        throw new BusinessError.CustomError(IdError);


    }
    finally
    {
        clsDatabase.oDataBase.Close();

    }
```

My stored procedure looks like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[examplaire_Create] 
    @date_achat dateTime,
    @date_emprunt dateTime,
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [bibliotheque].[dbo].[exemplaire] ([date_achat],[date_emprunt])
    VALUES (@date_achat, @date_emprunt) 
END
```

And of course my columns in db are the right type `datetime`.

I can add a row in db directly, it throws the error only when I try to insert using datagridview

Here is how I call my DAL in the Business layer:

```
 DateTime achat = Convert.ToDateTime(oRow["date_achat"]);
 DateTime emprunt = Convert.ToDateTime(oRow["date_emprunt"]);

 DataAccessLayer.Exemplaire.CreateExemplaire(achat, emprunt);
```

What am I missing ?

I can execute the stored procedure via SQL Server Management Studio in this way and it works fine

```
declare @date_achat as datetime=datetimefromparts(2016,1,25,17,0,0,0)
declare @date_emprunt as datetime=datetimefromparts(2016,2,25,17,0,0,0)

execute examplaire_Create  'jljljj', @date_achat, @date_emprunt, 1
```

Comment: If you pass parameters of type DateTime to your stored procedure, what is the sense of calling Convert(datetime,.....) on them? They are already a DateTime type

Comment: And looking again to your stored procedure. A comma is missing between the two convert and that @id_biblio seems to be the integer that the engine tries to convert to a datetime. Please fix your typos and check if you still have errors.

Comment: i was just tesing if that was what i miss but you're right the soredt procedure doesn't need to convert

Comment: there are others column ,but im my question i didin't put it because nothing was wrong with them

Comment: Your stored procedure code is not correct. The part with values should be separated by commas. Right click your stored procedure and execute it. enter some values and make sure your stored procedure is working before you call it from code.

Comment: actually in my code ,it's there but thanks i am going to try make the procedure work n sql before anything else

Comment: Your stored procedure definition has an extra comma after the second parameter definition and when you call it you have `,1` at the end. Is this just a cut and paste error from creating the question?

Comment: as iexaplined i 've got 2 others paramater which doesn't trhows errors that's why you've got at the beginnning ''jljljj' and 1 at the end

Comment: @bob - can you show all the code related to calling the stored procedure? (`CreateExemplaire` function body)

Comment: is the first block of code,i didn't show it all

Comment: From @surya: Everything is looking fine.In procedure you are trying insert two columns with three values.so i thought you are getting issue

Comment: actually i've  got 4 paramaters my only issue is 2 of them the one with datetime type